# *.service is escaped as \x2a.service in Ubuntu20.04 server

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, systemd

I have a bash script where I'm looping through all the service files in a folder. Like below:

```
for f in ./service_files/*.service; do
   sudo systemctl enable "${f##*/}"
   sudo systemctl start "${f##*/}"
done
```

However, I am getting errors and warnings.

> Glob pattern passed to enable, but globs are not supported for this.
>
> Invalid unit name ".service" escaped as "\x2a.service".
>
> Failed to enable unit: Unit file \x2a.service does not exist.
>
> Warning: systemctl start called with a glob pattern.

However, the same bash script is working for Ubuntu 18.04 desktop image.

I have systemd version: 245

Any idea how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like `./service_files/*.service` is failing to match anything, and you haven't set the `nullglob` option in your script, so that you are passing literal `*.service` to the systemctl commands

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly means "*Like* below"? Can you reproduce the problem with the script shown in the question or only with a more complicated script? How do you run the script? What is the current working directory? Is there a subdirectory `service_files` in the current directory? Run your script with `bash -x your_script` or insert a line `set -x` to see what actually gets executed.